# How can I have acces to an object written with stdout?

Tags: python, json

Hi I'm new with python and I want to know how can I have acces to the json part in the result variable. I don't want to create a json file I just want to have acces to the variable "result". I know that sys.stdout have a role in that, can someone help me and give me an explanation of sys.stdout?

```
file = open(args.output, 'w', encoding="utf-8") if args.output else sys.stdout
file.write(result.to_json(indent=2))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign it to a variable:

```
js = result.to_json(indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused; if you just want the result variable, then you seem to already have it. If you want the object recreated from the json object, you could simply recreate it.

```
resjson = result.to_json(indent=2)
res_from_json = json.loads(resjson)
```